# WebRtc Maximum Connections, only using data channels

Tags: connection, webrtc, max, p2p

My question is if I plan to use WebRTC with a p2p architecture but only using its custom data channel to send constant small text messages. ¿What is the maximum number of peer connections that a peer can support? (I know this its heavily going to depend on the device, network... of each peer, but could somebody give me a ballpark estimate).

Edit: By constant text messages i mean around 30 / sec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of limitations might be maximum amount of available ports in the device's OS. For example, Ubuntu has about 65k available ports. So, supposing that you have enough memory, CPU and network bandwith, and 1 port for 1 data channel then you have ~65k connections.

Comment: Ty for answer, thats way more than i need